# GET request returns null in android 6

Tags: android, rest, get

Helo,

I have a setup where I am able to post the json data to database(mongodb) successfully. But the code written to retrieve the same data in the android app is not working. The app is giving null. The GET is working if I try from REST API client  of google. Could anyone please help.
This is my code:

Android Code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main7Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String username;
    public String result;
    EditText contents;
    //public String result;
    public EditText serial1;
    public String serial;
    StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main7);
        Intent intentExtras = getIntent();
        Bundle extraBundle = intentExtras.getExtras();
        username=extraBundle.getString("username");
        serial1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.serial);
        serial=serial1.getText().toString();
        contents=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.contents);
        }
    public void ret(View v) {

            serial=serial1.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(Main7Activity.this, ""+serial , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(serial))
            {
                serial1.setError("Please Enter the Serial Number");
            } else {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://10.43.106.94:8080/SRNSmartLab/rest/service/getNEdata" + serial);
                System.out.println(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                System.out.println(in);
                if (in.readLine() == null) {
                    contents.setText("No data found");
                }
                String str1;
                while ((str1 = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    content.append(str1 + "\n");
                    contents.setText(content);
                }
                in.close();
                System.out.println(content.toString());
               } catch (Exception e) {
                result = e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(Main7Activity.this, "" + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Code:

```
@GET
    @Path("/getNEdata/{deviceId}")
    public Response getDeviceData(@PathParam("deviceId") String deviceId) {
        List deviceDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("The data is " +deviceId);
        Mongo mongo;
        DBCollection collection;
        DB db;
        try {
            mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
            DB db = mongo.getDB("nedata");
            // connecting to 'SRN' collection
            collection = db.getCollection("nodeinfo");
            BasicDBObject t = new BasicDBObject();
            t.put("SerialNO", deviceId);
            DBCursor cursor = collection.find(t).limit(10);
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                deviceDataList.add(cursor.next());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(500)
                    .entity("Exception Occured while getting device slist")
                    .build();
        }

        if (deviceDataList == null)
            return Response.status(204).entity("No content Found!").build();
        else
            return Response.status(200).entity(deviceDataList.toString())
                    .build();

    }
```

Thanks,Alby

Comment: The App gives the response as "null" as error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null error was rectified after adding the following:

```
private class GetClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private final Context context;
        public String url;
        public String displayParm;
        public GetClass(Context c) {
            this.context = c;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
//        progress= new ProgressDialog(this.context);
//        progress.setMessage("Loading");
//        progress.show();
            Log.w("var23", "loading");
        }

protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Log.w("var23", "doInBackground url : " + this.url);
//            final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showOutput);
                URL url = new URL( this.url );
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");
                connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.w("var23", "api hit in respomse"+String.valueOf(responseCode));
                final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code " + responseCode);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type " + "GET");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println("output===============" + br);
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseOutput.append(line);
                }
                Log.w("var24", "Result from API: " + responseOutput.toString());
                br.close();

                final JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(responseOutput.toString());
```